# How to loop search on same chrome instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class Search(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe') #This would open a new chrome instance but i need it to run in the same chrome instance until re.compile matches.
        self.driver.get("Site2")
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a").click()
        sleep(2)
        Texto = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/article[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/article/div[1]").text
        sleep(10)
        import re
        Id = re.compile('[0-9]{9}') #Format to match xxxxxxxxx 9 random numbers.
        if Id.match(Texto): 
            print ("Matches")
        else: #If its not a match re run Search 
            print("Not match")
            sleep (20)
            Search() 

class BasicBot(object):
    def __init__(self, username, pw):
#Enters site, logs in
        Search()#Runs search



BasicBot('cookiexplorer',"password")
```

I need to run the search class in the same chrome instance until the text i find matches the re.compile.
Im new to python so even my class def might be wrong.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? _Im new to python so even my class def might be wrong._ Personally I might not even use a class for this.

Comment: AMC you where totally right, a new class was not at all needed.